# Racket list in struct

Tags: list, struct, scheme, racket

I just started programming with Racket and now I have the following problem. 
I have a struct with a list and I have to add up all prices in the list.

```
(define-struct item (name category price))
(define some-items
(list
   (make-item "Book1" 'Book 40.97)
   (make-item "Book2" 'Book 5.99)
   (make-item "Book3" 'Book 20.60)
   (make-item "Item" 'KitchenAccessory 2669.90)))
```

I know that I can return the price with: `(item-price (first some-items))` or `(item-price (car some-items))`.

The problem is, that I dont know how I can add up all Items prices with this.

---

Answer to Óscar López:
May i filled the blanks not correctly, but Racket mark the code black when I press start and don't return anything.

```
  (define (add-prices items)
  (if (null? items)           
     0                   
      (+ (first items)                 
         (add-prices (rest items)))))
```

Comment: Is this homework? (you should tag it as such if it is) In any case, I think you should take a look at the chapter on [arbitrarily large data](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html) in HTDP2e to read up on how to design functions that operate on lists.

Comment: Agreed.  In particular, there's a chapter in How to Design Programs 2nd edition that talks about how to write functions that deal with lists of arbitrary size: http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html

Comment: @Tim Your base case is wrong - simply answer this question: what's the price of an empty list? zero! just write `0`. You can't add a number to a list like you did here: `(+ 0 items)`

Comment: Its still marked black.
Should I answer my own Question when ist works?

Comment: You still have serious, basic mistakes in your code, you didn't fill-in the question marks correctly. I second @dyoo's suggestion: you need to read a bit more before tackling the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: traverse the list using recursion. This looks like homework, so I'll give you some hints; fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (add-prices items)
  (if (null? items)            ; if the list of items is empty
      <???>                    ; what's the price of an empty list?
      (+ <???>                 ; else add the price of the first item (*)
         (add-prices <???>)))) ; with the prices of the rest of the list
```

(*) Notice that you *already* know how to write this part, simply get the price of the first item in the list using the appropriate procedures for accessing the value!

There are many ways to solve this problem. The one I'm proposing is the standard way to traverse a list, operating over each of the elements and recursively combining the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But it seems not to work correctly. I will edit the main Question.

Comment: @user1806829 maybe there's a problem in the way you filled-in the blanks, the above template for a solution works, I tested it. Place here (in the comments) how you filled each of the question marks

Answer (score 1):

use foldl and map:

```
(foldl + 0
       (map 
         (lambda (it)
           (item-price it))
             some-items))
```